# pass id and value to set of select input in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this  set of select input that shows numbers  on intail load on select filed and then i want to change value based on the option also i want to pass a id to the post api called user.id

```
{
  data.map((user) => (
    <select
      value={user.numberfromapi} // to show the number that is fecteched from api in intial load
      style={{ background: defaultcolor }}
      onChange={handleBackground(user.id ,value)} // i want to pass these 2 filds
    >
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `handleBackground` to look like this.

```
const handleBackground = (userId) => ({ target }) => {
  let value = target.value;

  // you can use userId and value here.
}
```

Then in your JSX call `handleBackground` like this.

```
<select
  value={user.numberfromapi}
  style={{ background: defaultcolor }}
  onChange={handleBackground(user.id)}
>
```

Or do it the *sloppy* way like this.

```
<select
  value={user.numberfromapi}
  style={{ background: defaultcolor }}
  onChange={(event) => handleBackground(user.id, event.target.value)}
>
```

Comment: plase help me with this

Comment: can u pls help me with this also sir i want to have differnt backgound colour for slect button when slected as if it is  ***1  i want red  ,  for 2 green , for 3 yellow ,for 4 blue***

Comment: You can keep a state variable which you will update in `handleBackground`. You can then use that state to update the button's color. There are many ways to implement this.

Comment: can pls provide a example sir i been trying that from yesterday